# Oracle - Cannot call a function prefixed by Schema name

Tags: oracle, function, schema

I have a problem with `Oracle 12C`, which I can't call a function with the schema name if this schema is active by default.

Example:

Current Schema is `StoreA`

If I call `StoreA.CalcSum()` it doesn't work.

Although if I call `CalcSum()` it works.

Is there any idea?

Comment: Hello, i got the folowing ERROR PLS-00302: component must be declared ...
Grant execute seems OK

Answer (score 0):

We found the problem, somone has created a table with the same name as the schema !!!!
Certainly a false manipulation with a restore :)

Thank to all :)